# Netbeans collapse variables

Tags: netbeans

In Netbeans, the minus icon for collapsing chunks of code appears next to functions, blocks, comments, and series of #include statements by default. Is there a way to collapse a series of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your variables using the following statements

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="My variables">
...
// </editor-fold>
```